# <dialog> only working on chrome

Tags: html

I want to use the `<dialog>` tag:

```
<dialog>
    <div id="start_conditions_scroll">
        <p>Conditions</p>
        <p class="condition">
            My Conditions
        </p>
    </div>
    <button id="close" class="button">Close</button>
 </dialog>
```

With this css:

```
dialog {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

dialog::backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

And this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

    document.querySelector("#show").onclick = function () {
        dialog.showModal();
    };

    document.querySelector("#close").onclick = function () {
        dialog.close();
    };
});
```

It is working perfectly on Google Chrome but only on google chrome as it seems (it is definetely not working on IE and Firefox!). Is there a workaround or anything special i have to do to make it working?

**EDIT**

sorry forgot to tell what is not working: the content of the dialog is shown on startup of the page in IE and Firefox. It should hide and after clicking the link the modal dialog should appear like it is in chrome.

Comment: Looks like this is [consistent with browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=dialog) at the moment. You really have to check out these newer features because until the major browsers implement something, it's pointless to use them.

Comment: Try `showModalDialog` as a fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, only in chrome or Opera.

You can test the compatibility here http://caniuse.com/#search=dialog

Comment: thank you. is there another way how i can achieve the dialog in IE and Firefox?

Comment: native of html you can not be , as best as Howard says use a js library.